# AddChart2 incompatible with Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have the code to draw a chart in VBA that works beautifully in Office 2013, but not 2010, and this seems to be the line:

```
.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
```

and the error '438' says:

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method was added in Office 2013, that's why you see this error.
See [AddChart2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228277.aspx)